# Intercept system commands from app

Tags: logging, 7.1-nougat, java

I'm on Android 7.1.2 (Nougat). I have an app that I am trying to pull the exact command /parameters that it is sending to one of my /system/bin apps. It is not in logcat and I haven't been able to find it with strace either.

What I'm looking to do is replace the bin file in /system/bin with another file and give it the same name so it logs the command/parameters that's sent to the binary. Is that possible? And is so how?  How would I go about getting this info.

Comment: As long as the binary is not required by the system this is possible. You just need an extended hello world program that prints all of it's arguments. But that should only be required if the command that is executed only runs for less than a second. Otherwise simply printing the command-line using `ps -Af` may be easier (just create a script that executes this command in a loop and redirect the output to a file you can examine later).

Comment: Android is not allowing me to use the command ps -Af stating that it is a bad pid.. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What phone are we talking about (manufacturer and exact model name). Also is the installed ROM a stock or a custom ROM?

Comment: I'm on a teclast P10 - Android 7.1.2.  I'm reading the PS binary got upgraded in android 8 to include -Af. I'm trying to see if I can swap binary. I may go the hello world route that you mentioned but I'm not that familiar with Android to know how to go about that easily.

Comment: You just need a BusyBox or TinyBox binary for arm cpu, copy it to `/data/local` or `/data/local/tmp`, there you can execute it like `busybox ps ...`

Comment: I have tried that. Busybox isn't giving me the option to use -Af either.